# Segmentation error in FCFS Scheduling code

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, system-calls

I was writing this code for FCFS scheduling. But in Linux this is giving 
"Segmentation error". How to correct such error?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
float fxn();

int main()
{

float avgwt;
int n,i,at[10],bt[10];
printf("\n\nEnter the number of processes:");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("\n\n BURST TIME and ARRIVAL TIME of thr process");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
printf("\n ARRIVAL TIME :");
scanf("%d",&at[i]);
printf(" BURST TIME : ");
scanf("%d",&bt[i]);
}

avgwt=fxn(at,bt,n);

printf("\n\nAverage waiting time=%f",avgwt);
return 0;

}



float fxn( int at[], int bt[], int n)

{

int i,j,t,wt[n],sum,tt[n],q;

float avgwt;


 for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
  {
   if(at[i]>at[j])

    {
t=at[i];
at[i]=at[j];
at[j]=t;
q=bt[i];
bt[i]=bt[j];
bt[j]=q;
    }
   }


wt[0]=0;


for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

wt[i+1]=wt[i]+bt[i];
sum=sum+(wt[i+1]-at[i]);

}

avgwt=sum/n;

return avgwt;


}
```

Another Question ----  I will be editing this code for making a system call in linux.

Will the passing of arrays will work if a c program will takes input from user and passes it to the kernel for further calculations?

(for example - here main() function for taking input and  fxn() function into the kernel

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add HOMEWORK tag. Have you tried using gdb to debug? Have you tried to determine where the error is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a buffer overflow below

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

  wt[i+1]=wt[i]+bt[i];
   sum=sum+(wt[i+1]-at[i]);
  }
```

it should be `i < n -1` also you need to intialize `i=0` in function `fxn`

Comment: @user1263375 look into this  `wt[i+1]=wt[i]+bt[i];sum=sum+(wt[i+1]-at[i]);`i just pointed out the seg-fault but there seems to be a logic error : intialize sum and in the existing logic `at[n-1]` and `bt[n-1]` are not accounted by `wt`

Answer (score 1):

A segmentation fault/error is an indicator of your program accessing memory (reading or writing), which doesn't belong to your program (meaning it has no "rights" to access it). This includes access of array members.

Now I see one possible and one definite problem in your code:

1. You read in a number of processes `n` and fill your arrays `at` and `bt` with `n` values. This is only correct as long as there are at most 10 processes, because you declared your  arrays to only have length 10.
2. In your function `fxn` (btw: are you sure you can't name this function any better?) you are creating an array `wt` of length `n` (also you create an array `tt` which you don't even use). To be technically correct `wt` is a so-called VLA or variable length array, which is notably only present in C99, which is a C standard which most compilers still don't fully support, so you might be wanting to avoid these (and e.g. use `malloc` and `free`). So what's the actual problem?

This:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

wt[i+1]=wt[i]+bt[i];
sum=sum+(wt[i+1]-at[i]);

}
```

`i` can have values from `0` to `n-1`, so `i+1` can have the value `n`, which is out of bounds of your array `wt`, causing a segfault.

You might also think about your array `wt`; you don't even need it! Just a tip.

Comment: and what about my 2nd Question? any clue?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you actually want to do, but if you are just system calling (like one does with `fopen`, `malloc` and so on), then yes, of course you can pass your arrays as arguments - as long as the function you are calling will expect these types (and as a side note: I don't know any system function which expects integer arrays; most of the times they expect special `struct`s). So yeah, I don't really know what to say to this.